# How do I use a loop to paste my selected "text" into cells?

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I'm trying to input text for example "code" into a column, using the Counta formula in two cells in my historic tab.

`mystart` and `mystop` both have Counta formulas in the cells and I want to paste the word "code" for example in all the cells between the two values, but I don't how to finish my code.

The text "code" will change thought out my code to something else

```
Sub MON_ImportHistory()

Sheets("Historic").Range("B2:AZ3000").ClearContents

'
If Worksheets("Help").Cells(18, 9) = "Data already present" Then
   MsgBox ("Import aborted: Data for selected date already present")

Else

Dim myRange As Range
Dim NumRows As Integer
Dim myCopyrange As Range
Dim mystart As Range
Dim mystop As Range



m_import = Worksheets("Help").Cells(17, 9)
m_criteria = "=" & m_import



Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "file on my data base"
Sheets("Historic").Select
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), m_import) > 0 Then
   m_Filterrange = "$A$1:$AV$" & Trim(Str(Worksheets("Historic").Cells(1, 18) - 1))
   ActiveSheet.Range(m_Filterrange).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
   m_criteria, Operator:=xlAnd

   m_extractrange = "$A$90000:$AV$" & Trim(Str(Worksheets("Historic").Cells(1, 18) - 1))
   Range(m_extractrange).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Windows("My File name").Activate
   Sheets("Historic").Select
   mystart = Worksheets("Historic").Cells(1, 19)
   mystop = Worksheets("Historic").Cells(1, 20)

   For x = mystart To mystop

   myDestination = "B" & Trim(Str(Worksheets("Historic").Cells(1, 19)))
   Range(myDestination).Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Windows("My file name").Activate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on here...First, it looks like you are using CountA formulas in the worksheet to do what you should be doing in VBA.  There is a lot of work around being done to make that work.  You are probably getting an error on the second line because you are trying to clear the contents of a sheet that has not been opened yet.  To find the number of occupied rows in a column you can use `LastRow = Sheets("Historic").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row`.  You should try to minimize or eliminate the use of `Select` and `Activate`. If you try to clean that up it may make more sense to you and me.  Don't forget to end the loop with `Next x`.

```
Sub MON_ImportHistory()

Dim LastRow, LastCol As Integer
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim m_import As String
Dim x As Integer

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Help")

'
If ws1.Cells(18, 9) = "Data already present" Then
   MsgBox ("Import aborted: Data for selected date already present")
   Exit Sub

Else


Workbooks.Open "C:\Somefile.xlsx" 'Here is where you put your filename

Set ws2 = Workbooks("Somefile.xlsx").Worksheets("Historic")

LastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = ws2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, 2), ws2.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).ClearContents

m_import = ws1.Cells(17, 9)

For x = 2 To LastRow

        ws2.Cells(x, 2) = m_import

Next x

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Darrell for the reply. I thought I would of got a error on the second line too but its working fine so I left it like that. What can I use instead of . Select and .Activate? The code works for what I need it to do so I scared to change it in case I mess it up. I know about the end of the loop It the middle I'm struggling with.

Comment: See the code I posted.  This is a much more efficient way to copy a value from one spreadsheet to a range in a newly opened file.  Not sure what the filtering was doing for you, but you couldn't paste a copied range into single cells in a loop anyway.  I assume your `CountA` formulas were just trying to get the number of cells as well.

Comment: Thanks Darrell that's a lot more efficient